# Suppressing or resolving compiler errors in goog.base

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I use Closure Compiler on my sources and recently decided to enable the most strict mode via `--jscomp_warning=reportUnknownTypes`. Alas, it triggered a lot of warnings inside the `goog.base` itself! I've fixed all the problems in my own code and now I'm looking for a way to silence/remove errors in the closure library code.

I tried to fix errors in `base.js` but quickly realized it's unfeasible. There are approximately 108 errors in the file and in most cases they are **real errors** because of `goog.base` doesn't care much about types: it's a common practice there to define a type like `{?}` or `{*}`.

I also tried to use `--warnings_whitelist_file` to silence warnings I don't care about but it didn't work either. For an error:

`..\js\google\base.js:204: WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
      cur[part] = opt_object;
      ^`

I tried different forms in the whitelist file but none has worked:

`..\\js\\google\\base.js:204  could not determine the type of this expression
..\\js\\google\\base.js:204  WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
..\js\google\base.js:204  could not determine the type of this expression
..\js\google\base.js:204  WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
../js/google/base.js:204  could not determine the type of this expression
../js/google/base.js:204  WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
..\js\google\base.js:204  WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
      cur[part] = opt_object;`

Does anybody have a **working solution** to have this mode enabled and not get spammed by the errors from the closure library itself?

I use latest Closure Compiler which is:

`Version: v20150315
Built on: 2015/03/17 14:18`

Comment: `reportUnknownTypes` is quite spammy and not generally recommended. Someday we'll get around to https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/152 (implementing a more nuanced version of that check) which we may recommend turning on.

Comment: Well, it is spammy but once I got all my errors fixed (sometimes with a hack, though) the code became much more correct. Several unnoticed bugs were fixed. So, in spite of all the troubles it's a very useful mode which I'd like to continue using.

Comment: Btw, I'm "ihsoft" on githab :) Recent bug to the compiler was from me.

Comment: If you use the Java API to run the compiler it is possible to configure a warning guard to not show the warnings. It should also be noted that while the type values are not know, they are expected to be unknown, a better check would not warning about value declared to be unknown.  There is a more limited but still very useful checks that are part of the conformance framework (a unknown this check and unknown class property check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I decided to go the path with silencing warnings in the `base.js`. For that I've investigated compiler sources (thanks to the authors it's open source) and I found out that flag description doesn't match its actual effect. The description says:

`A file containing warnings to suppress. Each line should be of the form <file-name>:<line-number>?  <warning-description>`

But in fact this guard intercepts matching *errors* and **converts** them into warnings. Moreover, line numbers are completely ignored. I see no use of this flag with such behavior but I bet authors had a good reason to implement it this way.

Anyways, I forked from the main branch and fixed flag's behavior. Now matched errors and warnings are actually *suppressed* (silenced). Line numbers are now considered in the matching.

Syntax of the whitelist file is very similar to the error/warning output. For example if you get error (or warning) like this:

`..\js\google\base.js:120: ERROR - could not determine the type of this expression
      if (goog.getObjectByName(namespace)) {
          ^`

Then the relevant record in the whitelist file will be:

`..\js\google\base.js:120  could not determine the type of this expression`

You may add content of multiline errors as comments preceding them with `#` but only first line will be used for matching.

If this is what you need you may obtain the binary via one of the two ways:

- Get the patched sources and build the binary yourself: [ihsoft/closure-compiler - Wiki](https://github.com/ihsoft/closure-compiler/wiki)
- Get the pre-built compiler binary: [ihsoft/closure-compiler - Release v1.0-tuned](https://github.com/ihsoft/closure-compiler/releases/tag/v1.0-tuned)